# How load amcharts after onclick with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I use amcharts for chart

My code is :

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(){
    var chartData = [
    {
        "date": "12:08",
        "distance": 500,
        "duration": 350
    },
    {
        "date": "12:09",
        "distance": 400,
        "duration": 3100
    },

    ];
    var chart;
    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        ...


        // WRITE                                
        chart.write("chartdiv");
    });
});
```

But this code not work !

How fixed it ?

I want after click on .click class , load charts

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the ready function cause that's only called once it loads in. Try to remove the ready part and see if it works okay.

Answer (score 0):

*Credit should go to Amcharts support team.*

I know this is has been a really old post. From your request it seems like you are trying to **delay chart initialization until user actively clicks on the chart**

I figured this may be help for any one looking for this could get some help.[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ashgadala/pen/EoRwjV)

```
 `https://codepen.io/ashgadala/pen/EoRwjV`
```